# Nested Unapply within an UnapplySeq

Tags: scala

So I'm trying to find out if I can nest the use of an `unapply` in an 
`unapplySeq`

For context, I'm using the Scala regex library to deconstruct numbers and evaluate them to a string representation.

i.e. 101 = one hundred and one

Given one case:

```
val tripleDigit: Regex = """^(\d)(\d)(\d)$""".r

def numberToString(num: Int): String = num.toString match {
    case tripleDigit(d1, d2, d3) => //turn into string
    //other cases
}
```

This all works as expected until I need to factor in the teen numbers (11 to 19) that cannot be evaluated to a string using other numbers

i.e. 31 => 30 = thirty + 1 = one

It can be done with a guard

```
case tripleDigit(d1, d2, d3) if isTeen(d1 + d2) => //turn into string
```

but was curious to see if it could be done as part of the extraction

```
object Teen{
    def unapply(arg: Seq[String]): Option[(String, String)] = {
      arg match {
        case d1 :: d2 :: Nil if isTeen(d1 + d2) => Some(d1 -> d2)
        case _ => None
      }
    }
  }
```

and then adding into the case statement

```
case tripleDigit(d1, Teen(d2, d3)) => //turn into string
```

This didn't work as the `unapplySeq` extracts to a varargs-like value that I cannot seem to supply to the nested `unapply` as a `List[String]` (As each anonymous element is treated as a String)

As far as I know, the only way to get the remaining elements as a list is with `_*`

```
case tripleDigit(d1, dn @ _*) => //turn into string
```

My question is how do I supply the remaining `_*` list of elements to an `Unapply`.